# Python vectorization, how to get all index for every row with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, simulation

I'm having a hard time trying to solve this problem, the main issue is I'm running a simulation, so for lops are mainly forbidden, I have a numpy array NxN, in this case mine is about (10000x20).

```
stoploss = 19.9 # condition to apply
monte_carlo_simulation(20,1.08,10000,20) #which gives me that 10000x20 np array
mask_trues = np.where(np.any((simulation <= stoploss) == True, axis=1)) # boolean mask
```

I need some code to make a new vector of len(10000) which returns an array with all the positions for every row, lets suppose:

```
function([[False,True,True],[False,False,True]])
output = [[1,2],[2]]
```

Again, the main problem resides in not using loops.

Comment: So `output` will be a list containing different length lists.  That will require some sort of row iteration even it is buried in `split`

Comment: Do you really need the indices by row?  What's wrong with the (100000, 20) boolean?  You can easily get a row count (sum) from the mask.  To use your list of lists, you'll have to iterate.  That mask could also be cast as a `scipy.sparse` matrix.  The `lil` format `rows` array would be the desired array of 'nonzero' column indices.

Comment: Hi  hpaulj, I needed the exactly posiiton because then I had to compare each one with the bid and sell price, I would be missing data just counting the number of times it happens or getting the first for each row. I'm from Spain so at 2am I was looking for an efficient solution more than a free of iterations one.

Comment: Why is this tagged simulation?  The source of the data seems to be irrelevant to your question.  Am I missing some way in which that's relevant?

Comment: Hi pjs, I tagged it because this is indeed part of a simulation. Nevertheless I understand your point and I promise to be more precise next time with the tags field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply this:

```
list(map(np.where, my_array))
```

performance comparison against Kasrâmvd's solution:

```
def f(a):
    return list(map(np.where, a))

def g(a):
    x, y = np.where(a)
    return np.split(y, np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1)

a = np.random.randint(2, size=(10000,20))

%timeit f(a)
%timeit g(a)


7.66 ms ± 38.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
13.3 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I'll demonstrate a sparse matrix approach:

```
In [57]: A = np.array([[False,True,True],[False,False,True]])
In [58]: A
Out[58]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])
In [59]: M = sparse.lil_matrix(A)
In [60]: M
Out[60]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 3 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [61]: M.data
Out[61]: array([list([True, True]), list([True])], dtype=object)
In [62]: M.rows
Out[62]: array([list([1, 2]), list([2])], dtype=object)
```

And to make a large sparse one:

```
In [63]: BM = sparse.random(10000,20,.05, 'lil')
In [64]: BM
Out[64]: 
<10000x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10000 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [65]: BM.rows
Out[65]: 
array([list([3]), list([]), list([6, 15]), ..., list([]), list([11]),
       list([])], dtype=object)
```

Rough time tests:

```
In [66]: arr = BM.A
In [67]: timeit sparse.lil_matrix(arr)
19.5 ms ± 421 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [68]: timeit list(map(np.where,arr))
11 ms ± 55.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: x,y = np.where(arr)
    ...: np.split(y, np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1)
    ...: 
13.8 ms ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Generating a `csr` sparse format matrix is faster:

```
In [70]: timeit sparse.csr_matrix(arr)
2.68 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [71]: Mr = sparse.csr_matrix(arr)
In [72]: Mr.indices
Out[72]: array([ 3,  6, 15, ...,  8, 16, 11], dtype=int32)
In [73]: Mr.indptr
Out[73]: array([    0,     1,     1, ...,  9999, 10000, 10000], dtype=int32)
In [74]: np.where(arr)[1]
Out[74]: array([ 3,  6, 15, ...,  8, 16, 11])
```

It's `indices` is just like the column `where`, while the `indptr` is like the `split` `indices`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `np.split()` and `np.diff()`:

```
x, y = np.where(boolean_array)
np.split(y, np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1)
```

Demo:

```
In [12]: a = np.array([[False,True,True],[False,False,True]])

In [13]: x, y = np.where(a)

In [14]: np.split(y, np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1)
Out[14]: [array([1, 2]), array([2])]
```